# Has the Python Language Reference made an error of omission when it comes to string literals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I've been studying the Python Language Reference carefully, for some Anki flashcards I'm writing. And it appears I've hit a snag while going over string literals.

See here: The function call `print("can't")` returns `can't`.

But I've been unable to find anything in the docs that suggests this is even possible!

Consider this excerpt of the formal definition:

```
shortstring     ::= "'" shortstringitem* "'" | '"' shortstringitem* '"'
longstring      ::= "'''" longstringitem* "'''" | '"""' longstringitem* '"""'
shortstringitem ::= shortstringchar | stringescapeseq
longstringitem  ::= longstringchar | stringescapeseq
shortstringchar ::= <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>
longstringchar  ::= <any source character except "\">
stringescapeseq ::= "\" <any source character>`
```

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

---

As you may be able to tell, the sequence `"can't"` is a **short-string**. That's because it is a group of zero or more **short-string items** surrounded by matching groups of double quotes.

And **short-string items** may either be **short-string characters** or **string escape sequences.**

Since there are no string escape sequences in the sequence `"can't"`, let's look at **short-string characters**. The definition says that the quote (') is *not* a **short-string character**.

Since the quote is not a **short-string character**, it makes sense that `print('can't')` throws a syntax error. Why doesn't `print("can't")` follow the same rules?

I feel like the Python Language Reference has made an error of omission here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `"can't"` starts with a double quote, you're allowed to have a single quote in the literal.

```
shortstringchar ::= <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>
```

By "the quote" the specification means the character (either ' or ") that opened the string literal. This allows you to have either single or double quotes in a string literal (without escaping) by enclosing the literal in the opposite quote characters.